# How will I know how much Ink I used based on the total papers used

Tags: php, if-statement, increment

So I wanted to make an IF statement where it will return the total Ink consumption based on the papers used.

One (1) box of Ink = 9,600 papers

What will be the right logic for this?

Here is my Code:

```
if ($total_papers <= 9600) {
    //the number of box will increment
    //so if the total is    19,200 it should return 2 boxes.

} else{ //not more than 1 box }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `if` statement cannot return anything. If you want to calculate Ink consumption based on the number of paper sheets used, just make a division and then a ceil:

```
$ink = ceil($total_papers/9600);
```

This way you can get the number of ink boxes used. Then you can use `$ink` within an `if` statement (or anywhere you like)

Comment: thank you! its now working!!

Comment: how is `ceil` appropriate? unless you want to calculate how many ink cartridges have been put in function. 11k sheets of paper would have used 1.1453 cartridges of ink.

Comment: @AlexAndrei, if you need 1.14 cartridges, then you need at least 2, since 1 won't be enough.

Comment: Yeah it seems the OP got his answer, I got thrown off by the question about total ink consumption. "how much ink I used". You can ignore me :)